# Extract the Data from Cell with?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to extract the data from the cell and have created a below formula but its not working. I have attached a sample sheet for better understanding any help will be much appreciated.

If a cell has this word `"COMPLETED"` then formula will load just Completed other wise those strings which has ?.

```
=ArrayFormula(LEFT(A3,FIND("...DONE=>",A3)-1))

=TRIM(MID(A3,SEARCH($D$2,A3)+LEN($D$2),255))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WjpvEfpndRJ-tTOF99mSF9knMyF5Sq_FVpxnnvbgHHg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution here

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,".* (COMPLETE) .*"),REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"^\*\*\* (.* )? "))))`

You use `REGEXEXTRACT` and if not `COMPLETE` you use the `REGEXEXTRACT`.
And if cell is empty you use second `IFERROR`

Comment: Thank you very very much. Its working perfect.

Comment: If it does not bother you can you please look into this issue @Swen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750910/extract-required-data-from-the-cell-through-formula

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example on the sheet, you can make use of Arrayformula, If, and REGEXEXTRACT functions to achieve what you stated above.

Here's a formula you can use on Cell B3 which not not only lists the status for each item but also leaves the cell blank if there was no entry: `=arrayformula(iferror(if(REGEXMATCH(A3:A,"COMPLETE")=True,"COMPLETE",REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"\- (.*?)\- M")),""))`

Note: Please make sure to remove any values on cells below B3 for this to work.

Here's an example screenshot of the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63aWh.png)

Comment: Hello, I've updated my answer to contain the correct function. Changed Match to another REGEX. Hope this helps!

Comment: nvm, saw there was already working answer above. lol. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.