# Extract Required Data from the Cell Through Formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract

I have been using below formula which extract the desired result from the cell but now i am trying to get more data from the cell and i have tried at my end to get further values from the cell but its not working.

I have attached a Google Sheet where data and desired result is available and as well my fomrula.

any help will be appreciated.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,".* (COMPLETE) .*"),REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"^\*\*\* (.* )? "))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WjpvEfpndRJ-tTOF99mSF9knMyF5Sq_FVpxnnvbgHHg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is a similar formula

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"\.\.\.(.*)|\*\*\*","")))`

You use `TRIM` only to reject empty spaces from beginning or end of result.

The formula keeps only everything between `***` and `...`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping again @Swen can you please hide the picture the data is sensitive.

Comment: I did hide it. BUT. NEVER publish sensitive data. You can change it to `JOHN - 2021 COMPLETE - XX - 03-01-2021` or like that. Again. NEVER TRUE DATA.

Comment: Thank you very much for sure i will.