# Extracting Data from the Cell Through Formula But does not pull some of the data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, find, match

I have been Extracting a data from the cell where i need more result but my formula is extracting some data but not the whole as i need.

I have attached a sheet below will appreciate if i could get a help.

My formulas.

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"\.\.\.(.*)|\*\*\*","")))
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, "DONE=>\s*.+\b"))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MKC1OWIj64v_mmuNM6mLFY9wMgLwl2mUxm6KnsM5arE/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try 1) `=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"(\*{3}.*?)(?:\s*?\.{3}DONE=>.*)?(\*{3})$","$1 $2")))` and 2) `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, "DONE=>.+\b"))))`

Comment: thank you very much 1st is working fine but second is still similar as i posted above  @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Do you mean the second one should return the whole string that contains `DONE=>`? `REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, ".*DONE=>.*")`?

Comment: Yes you are right it should return the whole string but except values with `?` and `2021 COMPLETE`

Comment: Aha, try removing those with `\s+(?:-(?:\s+[A-Z]+\?)+|2021\s+COMPLETE -)`, `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "\s+(?:-(?:\s+[A-Z]+\?)+|2021\s+COMPLETE -)", ""), ".*DONE=>.*"))))`

Comment: Thank you its working fine but still extract values with `?` for some cells

Comment: Now, I suspect you just want to remove all between the first and second hyphen, `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^([^-]*-)[^-]+-", "$1"), ".*DONE=>.*"))))`

Comment: Thank you very very much for the unbelievable help. Please post an answer so i could accept it. Thank you once again.

Comment: Your sheet is private @Mento Please make it public. Readers do not know what you have in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for sample. What do you want to keep?

Comment: Sorry to bother you brother @Swen the data is private i did not transfer it in sample shape. This is the only reason. I hope you would understand

Comment: "the data is private" and "I hope you would understand" No problem. We said [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750910/extract-required-data-from-the-cell-through-formula#comment117997463_66751628) NO sensitive data. You must change them in the sheet. But are published [here](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/6) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/4/) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/3). I am confused.

Comment: Alright let me add sample sheet.

Comment: I thought removing data from there will be permanently delete it but my bad luck. @Swen Link added to sheet.

Comment: @Mento Yes bad luck. Now exposed. Be careful next time. How you decide for cells B4, B6, B10 be empty? What's the catch? I don't understand it. Sorry

Comment: Because no such `MUKHML=>` string is available in that cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexps you can use are

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"(\*{3}.*?)(?:\s*\.{3}DONE=>.*)?(\*{3})$","$1 $2")))
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^([^-]*-)[^-]+-", "$1"), ".*DONE=>.*"))))
```

See the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/4/) and the [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/3). The third one - `.*DONE=>.*` - simply returns all the strings that contain `DONE=>` in them.

**Details**:

- `(\*{3}.*?)` - Group 1 (`$1`): three `*` chars and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*\.{3}DONE=>.*)?` - an optional string of zero or more whitespaces, `***DONE=>` and then the rest of the string
- `(\*{3})` - Group 2 (`$2`): `***` string
- `$` - end of string.

The `^([^-]*-)[^-]+-` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^-]*-)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any zero or more chars other than `-` and then a `-`
- `[^-]+-` - one or more chars other than `-` and then a `-` char.

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: Sir, sorry to bother you but issue is still persisting @Wiktor Stribiżew i have highlighted them in above attached sheet. I have tried as well to resolve at my end but its really hard to solve it.

Comment: @Mento You should use `^([^-]*- ).*? - ` or `^(.*? - ).*? - `, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7RyV7/6).

Answer (score 0):

You say "Thank you but it includes ? value in last"

**Completely new formula for your needs**
We put front part and last part together with `&`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"MUKHML"),TRIM((REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^[^-]*")&REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,".*\?|.* COMPLEXIES",""))),""))
```

[image]

---

Use this new formula like from Wiktor

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:a,"MUKHML"),REGEXREPLACE(A2:a,"^([^-]*-)[^-]+-","$1"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it includes `?` value in last

Comment: Did you try @Mento the Completely new formula for your needs? I am curious it works.

Comment: Maybe this must be accepted answer. Or users get confused. You decide.

Comment: Yes i would definitely do this if you posted this first.

Comment: No problem. But remember. It not time race. It about correct answer.